# Cannot use characters '<' or '>' in jQuery script in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery

While running my jquery script in wordpress I ran across this weird error. That does not allow me to use characters '<' or '>' in my script, any surrounding text just disappears during runtime.

For example

This:

```
trims = jQuery('#trims').append('<option>');
```

Becomes this (after rendering):

```
trims = jQuery('#trims').append('');
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am simply unable to create new elements using my script.

EDIT:

The script is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
jQuery("#submit-btn").on('click',function(){
    function readBody(xhr) {
        var data;
        if (!xhr.responseType || xhr.responseType === "text") {
            data = xhr.responseText;
        } else if (xhr.responseType === "document") {
            data = xhr.responseXML;
        } else {
            data = xhr.response;
        }
        return data;
    }
    var uservin = $('#input-vin').val();
    var vehicles = [];
    var trims = jQuery('#trims');
    var i = 0;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            xml = jQuery(jQuery.parseXML(readBody(xhr)) );
            jQuery(readBody(xhr)).find('Vehicle').each(function(){
                var vehicle = jQuery(this);
                vehicles.push(vehicle.attr("Trim_Level"));
                trims = jQuery('#trims').append('');

            });
            console.log(vehicles);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://ws.vinquery.com/restxml.aspx?accesscode=b02289a0-479a-41d0-aebe-xxxxx&vin='+uservin+'&reporttype=1', true);
    xhr.send(null);
});
});
</script>
```

The HTML body is:

```
[vc_row][vc_column width="1/2"][vc_wp_text]
<input class="form-control" id="input-vin" type="input"
placeholder="Enter VIN"/>
[/vc_wp_text][/vc_column]
[vc_column width="1/2"][vc_wp_text]
<input type="submit" id="submit-btn" class="form-control"/>[/vc_wp_text]
[/vc_column][/vc_row]
[vc_row][vc_column][vc_wp_text]
<select name="Trim_level" id="trims"></select>
[/vc_wp_text][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

Another update:

When trying to implement the following for loop:

```
for(i=0;i<vehicles.length;i++){}
```

It gets rendered as:

```
for(i=0;i
</script>
```

The rest of my script disappears from where the '<' appears.

Comment: What is `#trims` element?

Comment: share your whole code with html and whole javascript.

Comment: Where did you put your javascript? Does it come over a shortcode into the page?

Comment: Have you tried escaping it? `trims = jQuery('#trims').append('\<option\>');` should work as well AFAIK.

Comment: @dipmala didn't really mean _all_ your code. Only the relevant part ;)

Comment: @helle I added the code in the custom JS part for the theme

Comment: @AhmedBajra That did not work

Comment: which totaly does not answer my question :) and creates new: What is "vc"? where does that things come from? you didn't mention the use of a not common known vinquery framework ...

Comment: sorry @helle I am a Wordpress noob. I don't know what shortcode is, and it comes to the page through the theme

Comment: @helle The "vc" is used for grid display, it is from a plugin. The vinquery framework is an external api call I don't see how that would restrict use of tags

Comment: @ribhu97 if you use not-common things in wordpress it is not clear what happend around with those plugins. they can have immense impact on the behavior of the cms. so as I understand that, your js is parsed through something befor it comes to the html - because it is created by a shortcode (the things with the [ ] breakets, which don't look like html tags ;) ) 
Try to use 1. doublequotes ", and 2. try to escape the <,> breakets with a backslash ... and check the answert of Fatih who suggests to use that thing right, I think he knows your plugin as well.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Well double-quotes, escape characters or Fatih's method did not work. Maybe it is some issue with the grid organizing plugin, I'll try another way. Thanks for your help. I'll learn more about shortcodes and try implementing that

Answer (score 2):

cannot append option alone

you must use below

```
trims = jQuery('#trims').append('<select><option></option>......</select>');
```

2 3 days ago I did not meet this problem. Solve this way

Comment: `#trims` is a `select` element.

Comment: That did not work

Comment: pick element into div container. #trims must be div element